# "Made a rhyme without effort" in English from Spanish "Hice verso sin esfuerzo"

Tags: poetry, proverbs, rhymes, spanish, aphorism-requests

In Spanish we can say "Hice verso sin esfuerzo", which means something along the lines of "I made a rhyme without effort", whilst rhyming.

What would be an English equivalent of this phrase?

I've come up with a couple of variations, a couple of weeks ago, but they weren't really valid English or had to do with effort, I don't think.

Comment: You're a poet and don't know it.

Comment: @Jim Beat me by 2 seconds!

Comment: @Jim that does rhyme and gets the message across, but it only works if the other person does the rhyme. What about if I made the rhyme and I'm saying that I made a rhyme?

Comment: I'm a poet and didn't know it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I guess that counts. lol. Feels kinda cheap to modify it like that though. lol

Comment: Do _esfuerzo_ and _verso_ rhyme in Castilian Spanish?

Comment: @JohnLawler That only rhymes in standard Spanish because Spanish rhyming is assonant: it only cares about vowels not any involved consonants.  *Verso* is `/ˈβ̞eɾso/` compared with *esfuerzo* `/esˈfweɾθo/`. That’s why in “Canción del jinete”, Lorca could rhyme *Jaca negra, luna grande, /
y aceitunas en mi **alforja.** /
Aunque sepa los caminos, /
yo nunca llegaré a **Córdoba.***  In assonant rhyme, *alforja* and *Córdoba* rhyme. See all of Lorca’s other pieces in his *Romancero Gitano* for virtually infinite examples of this.

Comment: @JohnLawler Or in short: in Spanish-style assonant rhyme, yes, but in English-style consonant rhyme, no. Also, the rising diphthong in `/we/` just counts as the central vowel.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the explanation. :) Yes English and Spanish have different ideas of what makes a rhyme rhyme.

Comment: Greduan, @AndrewLeach hasn't modified it, it's a perfectly common saying. So he not that cheap :)

Comment: @Mynamite OK, fair enough. It doesn't quite carry the message I'm looking for though, so I'll just keep this open for a couple of days to see if somebody comes up with another rhyme for it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don’t mind some witless doggerel that may not suit the next inaugural:

*I make a rhyme             up all the time

        In easy verse                  that’s good and terse.

        They take no thought,   these words I’ve wrought;

        Though poets curse,      it could be worse.*

I must confess to some ambivalence  in seeking out the best equivalents.

Comment: Holy crap those are really good! My favorite being the third as it's the closest to the original Spanish version, IMO. Thanks! I'll just check back in a couple of days to check if somebody has a better version, if they don't I will accept yours. :)

Comment: All right, looks line nobody has more of these. I'll accept your question, thanks! :)

Comment: @Greduan You can think of the posted text in a variety of flexible fashions. I did not originally intend it to be four separate answers, but just a single quatrain.  That why I rhymed *good and terse* with *could be worse*. However, the internal masculine rhyme in feet 2 and 4 of each line of iambic tetrameter makes them potentially usable individually, like your Spanish example had. Lines 1, 3, and 4 could each stand on their own, or lines 1+2 could stand alone as a couplet. **Plus** the inner quatrain nests in an outer one whose last foot is instead a dactyl in feminine rhyme.

Comment: The amount of, I assume grammatical words you just said has given me a lot to study. lol I did not realize it was a quatrain (a word I just learnt), reading it like that makes it sound very good. After looking at the dictionary for a bit you are basically telling me which lines I could use and also you are explaining how you made the quatrain. Is this correct? Sorry I am inept in poetry.

Comment: @Greduan  Yes, that’s essentially right; they’re poetic terms, some from Greek. I intentionally wrote the outer quatrain’s two couplets straight out without a linebreak and in non-italic, so that it might not be so obvious upon first reading that there was something trickier going on. Read both the English and Spanish versions of [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_(prosody)), and definitely check out Stephen Fry’s referenced *The Ode Less Travelled: Unlocking the Poet Within* if you can get your hands on a copy. It’s short but very witty, per his wont.

Comment: OK cool. Thanks! Will definitely add that to my reading list, thank you. :)

Answer (score 5):

As has been mentioned in comments, "I'm a poet and didn't know it" is a common enough phrase.

Comment: Yup, thanks. :) It doesn't quite carry the message I'm looking for though, so I'll just keep this open for a couple of days to see if somebody comes up with another rhyme for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It took no time to type this rhyme.